# Can Norton Family warn the user shortly before a time limit arrives?

Tags: parental-controls, norton-family

## Background

I have ADHD and have been struggling with Internet overuse.  I've been off my ADHD medication lately and hope to discuss this with my psychiatrist eventually.  I've tried [twelve-step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:RFW#Corrective_strategies), and am also planning to contact a [doctor with an interest in addiction medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:RFW#Corrective_strategies).

The Internet overuse has caused me wrist pain and back pain at times.

There's a variety of [software that may help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:RFW#Software_that_may_help).  As for me, I've installed [Norton Family](http://family.norton.com).

## My question

I'm using Windows 10.

Norton Family allows me to set up time restrictions (e.g. a maximum limit of 2 hours of total Internet use per day).

Can Norton Family warn me a few minutes before cutting me off?

I've checked the [relevant online help document](https://family.norton.com/familysafety/help.fs?action=allowChildWeekdays) and the [instruction manual](https://onlinefamily.norton.com/familysafety/help/NSMHelpPdf/eng/Norton_Family_Help.pdf), and I've not found an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I wrote my question, but before I posted it, I did a Google search for [ `norton family warn before time restrictions` ].  I discovered that Wikipedia's ["Norton Family"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Family) article contains the answer to my question:

> Parents can define a range of hours when children are blocked, with separate settings for each child, weekdays and weekends. A daily time quota can be configured as well. **Children receive a warning 15 minutes prior before blocks begin or a time limit is exceeded. The amount of time left can be checked via the Norton Family system tray icon.** In the last minute before forced logout, children can postpone it by pressing a button, disabling the desktop and leaving only the Norton Family icon functional. Parents can then enter their credentials to grant a time extension. The time-management feature can also warn children, rather than cutting off access. Exceeding limits will result in a log entry. Time limits are enforced across multiple PCs. Changing the system time does not affect Online Family. The activity will be logged, however.

[Emphasis added.]